# Namespace works for a class, but won't work for others

Tags: php, namespaces

I am working on a PHP project and I am still learning how to apply namespaces to it. I've come up with the following situation:

File structure is

```
app.php
index.php
bar.php
sandbox
   \_index.php
   \_Foo.class.php
```

The contents of the files are as follows:

**app.php**

```
<?php
function strtocapital($string)
{  
    return substr(strtolower($string), 0, strrpos($string, '/')) . substr(strtoupper($string), strrpos($string, '/'), 2) . substr(strtolower($string), strrpos($string, '/') + 2);
}

function autoloader($className)
{
    $path = __DIR__ . '/' . strtolower($className) . '.php';

    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) !== 'WIN') {
        $className = str_replace('\\', '/', $className);
        $path = __DIR__ . '/' . strtolower($className) . '.php';
    }

    if (!is_file($path)) {
        $className = strtocapital($className);
        $path = __DIR__ . '/' . $className . '.class.php';
        if (!is_file($path)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    include_once $path;
    echo "Successfully loaded ${className}<br>";
}

spl_autoload_register("autoloader");
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'app.php';

use Sandbox\Foo as Fuu;

echo __DIR__ . '<br>';

$foo = new Fuu();

try {
    echo $foo::FOOFOO;
    $foo::foofoofoo();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

**bar.php**

```
<?php
class Bar
{
    const BARBAR = "dada";

    public static function barbarbar()
    {
        echo "Bar bar bar";
    }
}
```

**sandbox/index.php**

```
<?php
require '../app.php';

use Bar;

echo __DIR__ . '<br>';

$bar = new Bar();

try {
    echo $bar::BARBAR;
    $bar::barbarbar();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

**sandbox/Foo.class.php**

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    const FOOFOO = "bla";

    public static function foofoofoo()
    {
        echo "Foo foo foo";
    }
}
```

Despite the fact I receive both successful messages:

```
Successfully loaded Sandbox\Foo
Successfully loaded Bar
```

I only see the outputs for Bar class. The difference between them is that `sandbox/index.php` returns HTTP Status 200 and `index.php` returns HTTP Status 500. However, I see no errors, even after trying `error_reporting(E_ALL)`.

Please help me on this, because doing the same steps for both classes and having one working and the other not is driving me nuts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you apply the namespace or am I missing something? I see where you applied the alias but not the namespace. If I am correct and not missing anything you have to add your namespace at the VERY top of your classes file. Something like  -- namespace foo; or namespace bar; or whatever your using when you use your use alias.

Comment: Thank you, Joe. I've previously read that `use` keyword actually uses folders structure if they are strictly the same, but it happens to be working now that I added `namespace` to `Bla.class.php`.

Comment: I am going to add this as an answer so that you may mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying namespace at the top of the page that is using the bar or foo namespace it will define the namespace and work. Do this like so:

```
namespace foo; #Or namespace bar; or whatever your namespace is.
```

You can apply that on any page that you need to use that namespace on. A good tutorial on this would be https://www.sitepoint.com/php-53-namespaces-basics/.